# How to find the value of Column A on the first instance of Column B > Column C

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

Given the below table

[image]

I have Column A as a unique key value, I am looking to return the first key value where `B < C`

In this case the first instance is `A = 3` Where `B = 4` and `C = 5`

Can someone help me understand the `LOOKUP` formula to return the value 3?

Comment: The problem is not very clearly, where do you wan to return the value? Is B>C the condition or reference? Try to provide more information.

Comment: don't you mean B<C?

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the below:

```
=INDEX(A1:A4,MIN(IF(C1:C4>B1:B4,ROW(A1:A4),100000)),1)
```

Enter this as an array formula by pressing Ctl + Shift + Enter to enter it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I try to create a sample with auxiliary columns, I entered 2 columns

1: Is B>C?

```
=B2>C2
```

[image]

2: Count FALSE number:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($E$2:E2=FALSE)*($E$2:E2=E2))
```

[image]

3: Get the result:

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(1,F2:F5,0))
```

[image]